# Project doesn't run in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I can't run my project in an Android Studio. When i click on the run button the gradle build once then nothing happens after that i run app again and again but nothing happens

choose device or emulator window does not appear.Studio does not show any error.I have tried all of  my effort like edit configuration or clean project or make changes in settings .

Comment: May be there is no activity to display when app runs

Comment: I have created new project again and again but problem remains same

Comment: how you have overcome this